# Bootstrap 3.0 textinput is shorter in chrome compare to firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3.0

Why is it in chrome the width of textinput is shorter compare to the firefox.

Here's the screenshot.

**This is for Chrome**
[image]

**This is for Firefox**
[image]

As you can see the Firefox has a longer textinput. Basically, I am not sure if what's the problem with this one, is it Firefox or Chrome? but overall, I wanted to follow Firefox's style(longer textinput).

This is the HTML:

```
 <div class="search-wrapper">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
      <div class="input-group date col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xs-12">
        <span class="input-group-addon add-on getStarted hidden-sm hidden-xs"><img src="images/get-started.png"/></span>
        <input id="searchJobInput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for Jobs... Nurse, Pharmacist" style="height:55px;">
        <span class="input-group-addon add-on searchIcon"><img src="images/search-button.jpg"/></span>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank You!

Comment: can you provide a link to the live site?

Comment: @koala_dev Can I just send the link to your privately? Thanks! :)

Comment: Do you have both browser windows open at the same width? Because bootstrap 3 is responsive the size of the browser window will affect the width of the input box.

Answer (score 1):

Simply define the width for your input box in your css and it will override and browser defaults.

Also, ask yourself, [do websites need to look exactly the same in every browser?](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `input-group` and `col-*` classes on the same element; you should use nesting instead. This is mentioned in the docs.

Instead of:

```
<div class="input-group date col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xs-12">
```

You should use:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8">
  <div class="input-group date">
```